# Django money and ordering by min-max price

Tags: django

Hello i am making Django e-commerce app and i have a problem i wanted to make sorting thing. The problem is i do not know how to get prices between min-price - max-price and filter items.

```
HTML: 

<div class="sort__prices">
            <input class="sort__min-price" type="number" name="min-price" placeholder="minimum price">
            <input class="sort__max-price" type="number" name="max-price" placeholder="maximum price">
         </div>
         <button class="submit">sort</button>
```

views:

```
def sortView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        min_price = request.GET.get('min-price')
        max_price = request.GET.get('max-price')
        items = Item.objects.all().filter(price=min_price)

    return render(request, 'shop/sort.html', {'items': items})
```

Comment: The problem is i cant get the item with minimum price. And Vice versa i cant get item with maximum price. When i write 2 and item is 2$ i dont get him i have to write 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Q` objects to filter the prices.

```
from django.db.models import Q

items = Item.objects.filter(Q(price__gte=min_price) & Q(price__lte=max_price))
```

Read more about [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them and then pick the lowest or highest one:

```
items_list = list(Item.objects.all())

lowest_price = sorted(items_list)[0]
highest_price = sorted(items_list, reverse=True)[0]
```